# Text over image using CSS transitions

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, dreamweaver, rollover

I am an illustrator making a portfolio site.
I'm trying to simply create a rollover css transition with Dreamweaver. I would like it so when you roll over the image the text will rise up to give a description about the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j4qYh/)?

What I've done is, I've created two classes (`.pic` and `.text`). `.pic` holds the picture and the other class contains the text. The `.text` class is positioned at the bottom of `.pic` and it has a `height` of `0;` To make the text appear when you `:hover` over the image I just transition the height of `.text`, in this case from `0` to `150px;`

Here the code from my demo

**HTML**

```
<div class="pic"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
    <div class="text"><p>This is a cat</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pic {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0;
    text-align: center;    
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    transition: height 0.7s ease-out;    
}

.pic:hover > .text {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: No problem, but please tick the answer as correct if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Did it ! I am a little bit confused further now, every-time I put this new component inside my old layout, when viewing it in design view its on the other side of the page but in a browser its in place :s

Answer (score 0):

by rolling over the image, do you mean mouse-over event? this can be done in multiple ways. but probably if you dont have too much css or javascript knowledge. then just download an image caption plugin. one such plugin that comes to my mind is called jquery capty. just google it and follow instruction of adding like 2 lines of code. its that simple.
another way is using CSS positioning of the caption text over the image and use display:none initially and on mouse hover event, use the css :hover pseudo class and give it display: inline-block.  hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to add a `:hover` event within your `CSS` file once you're within Dreamweaver.

Something similar to this:

```
.class {
    background: blue;
}

.class:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SAy9N/)

This is not something that I've seen Illustrator be able to do and transfer it to Dreamweaver