# Text over image CSS Chrome Error

Tags: html, css

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675760/text-over-image-using-css-transitions) from this question: [Text over image using CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675760/text-over-image-using-css-transitions).
It's working fine in both IE11 and Firefox Quantum and in both sites the animation/transition works perfectly but when I try to visualize it in Chrome the text that should appear beneath the image and eventually hover it goes to the bottom of the page. The console also shows me zero errors.

My question resumes in if it is a CSS absolute attribute problem or something else.

Here's my code:

```css
.size {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.pic:hover > .text {
  height: 190px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -40px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0px;
  transition: height 0.7s ease-out;
  background-color: #fed136;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px #fed136;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text > h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  margin: 10px 10px 50px 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="pic animated zoomIn">
      <img src="someimage.jpg" class="size" />
      <div class="text">
        <h4>Some Title</h4>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and jQuery 2.1.4

Comment: So when i hover over the img a yellow box pops up in the bottom left corner with text on it. and i'm on chrome. i don't understand what is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you want is for the rollover text to be *inside* the image.

In this case I don't even know how it's working on IE11 or Firefox in your computer because here it fails on all browsers I have.

Your problem is basically that you are applying the CSS in the wrong element. Change `.size` to `.pic` in your CSS and it will get what you want.

Without `position: relative` inside `.pic` your `position: absolute` in `.text` is  relative to the page itself (or the html element) and not the `.pic` element.

You also need `overflow: hidden` to hide any elements that go beyond the borders of the `.pic` element, thus hiding `.text`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, honestly I don't know either how it worked in IE but it did. Thanks for your answer it works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Added position relative & overflow as hidden to container div 'pic' and made height of div 'text' to zero. Its working fine in Chrome without any error and in IE too.

```css
.size {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative

}
.pic {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.pic:hover > .text {
    height: 190px;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height:0;
    bottom: -40px;
    right: 0;
    left:0px;    
    transition: height 0.7s ease-out;
    background-color: #fed136;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px #fed136;
    padding: 10px;

}
    .text > h4 {
        text-align:center;
    }

.block {    
    margin:10px 10px 50px 10px;
    float:left;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="pic animated zoomIn">
                <img src="someimage.jpg" class="size" />
                <div class="text">
                    <h4>Some Title</h4>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties for diferent browsers. First clear your cash and see if the problem is realy only i Chrome. Then you can create something like that :
`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .container {-chrome-:only(; 
     property:value;
  );}`